# Overwrite the style of ComboBoxItem in ComboBox style

Tags: silverlight, combobox, styles

I have a Silverlight project and I want to customize the appearance of ComboBox control, so I add a ResourceDictionary.xaml file, overwrite the default style of ComboBox, apply this new style to ComboBox, and it works fine.

```
  <Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="CommonComboBoxStyle">
     <Setter Property = "xxx" Value="XXX" />
     ....
  </Style>
```

Soon I realized that I also need to customize the appearance of ComboBoxItem, I want to change its background color when an item is selected/mouseovered, so I overwritten its default style:

```
  <Style x:Key="FilterDownComboBoxItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
     .....
     <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="#FF0054A6" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="0" RadiusX="0"/>
     <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Fill="#FF0054A6" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="0" RadiusX="0"/>
  </Style>
```

Here is the question, I want to put FilterDownComboBoxItemContainerStyle in CommonComboBoxStyle, so I just need to apply CommonComboBoxStyle to ComboBoxes that I want, no need to apply FilterDownComboBoxItemContainerStyle separately to every ComboBoxItem, are there any ways to set style of ComboBoxItem in ComboBox style?

Answer (score 1):

> are there any ways to set style of ComboBoxItem in ComboBox style?

Yes, you can use [`ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.95).aspx) for this:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="CommonComboBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource FilterDownComboBoxItemContainerStyle}" />
</Style>
```